# Spotfire - modify data in a column for marked rows

Tags: spotfire

How would I add values to a column for marked rows in a scatterplot visualization. IE mark data in the visualization, press a button in a text area, change the value of a column to match the value assigned to the button for the marked rows only.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the underlying values in a data table. If you want to manipulate the data you need to use calculated columns. A calculated column can be based on the underlying imported data column.

Use a document property in your calculated column to change how it is calculated. Your button can change the document property.